# Doxygen - Ini as a Text?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, ini

I am starting to dokumenting with doxygen and as far as it goes it seems quite easy and helpful !
There is just one file which gives me a headache, my config.ini .
This file has different comments, standards etc. .
I would like to load it as "code", so the page is not interpreted.

How can I achieve this ?

The following didn't work :
; /// @file config.ini
; /// @code
setting1
setting2
setting3
; /// @endcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but I assume from your question that you *do* want to see the contents of the .ini file in the documentation.

For what I think you need I'd suggest using `@verbatim` rather than `@code`.

If you are not seeing anything at all, then check that `.ini` is in the list of filename extensions that doxygen will parse?  It's a setting in the doxyfile.

Comment: ini is in the list of filename extensions and it is parsed.
What I want is this the config.ini in the filetree.
When I open the informations to that ini, I would like to see the ini as it's code, and not interpreted by doxygen. In otherwords I need the whole ini content between the commentblocks, which doesn't work ...

Comment: Still a bit confused - can I break the question down:  1. Is config.ini in the file tree?  2. Do you see the text between the comment blocks at all? 3. What does it look like (what do _you_ mean by _interpreted by doxygen_?)  Is it merged like text, or syntax-coloured like code, or...?  4. Does it change if you use `@verbatim` instead, as suggested?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. yes, but interpreted as variables with partly wrong comments etc.
3. Look at 2
4. It didn't at first

5. I'm stupid, verbatim is the right idea and it works now. Changed the "///" to /** so doxygene sees the content of the ini as a comment. My own scripts still accept it as a ini-context :)

Comment: @abcNocturn Any particular reason for the -15 rep Anti-acceptance on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want as follows:

Define a page that includes the .ini file, for instance `test.dox` as follows:

```
/** @page test_ini test.ini
 *  This is the configuration file:
 *  @verbinclude test.ini
 */
```

Then set `EXAMPLE_PATH` in doxygen's config file to the directory that contains test.ini and don't include .ini files in `FILE_PATTERNS` (so use the default).